# IE8 - Compatibility Mode Spreads Page Out

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I have a web page that i have written in mainly HTML. When I run my website from visual studio 2008 the page looks fine. The problem is when I publish it IE8's compatibility mode spreads the page out.

BEfore my page used to be spread out because I had alot of hidden cells in tables that had cell spacing and padding. But I fixed all of that. And it looks great when I turn compatibility mode off.

I seem to think it's because I have some labels that are hidden that are still taking up space but not being shown. I am not sure though.

Are there any common solutions to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is to prevent compatibility mode by forcing IE8 to stick to IE8 mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

You'll never need to worry about the disaster that is IE7-compatibility mode again.

Comment: IE=edge means that you're planning to update your page when IE9 and IE10 and IE11 etc come out. If you don't want to touch it, use IE=EmulateIE8

Comment: @EricLaw -MSFT : Odds are IE9 won't have an IE8 mode anyway (the beta version doesn't), so it'll be a moot point. In any case, if IE9 lives up to its promises, I can't see any reason why anyone would want to hobble it by using a compatibility mode on it.